# <a> Hyperlink does not match where browser actually goes? PHP is used to write the tag programatically, but getting nested link structure

Tags: php, html, apache, web-development-server

Currently, I'm trying to make a simple blogging system using PHP. My website set up so all routing goes to `index.php`. It is extremely flimsy, and needs to be fixed up, however here it is right now

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $requestedPage = $_GET['page'] ?? 'home';
    if ($requestedPage === 'index'){
        $requestedPage = 'home';
        }
    $requestedPage = basename($requestedPage).".php"; 
    if (!file_exists($requestedPage)){
        http_response_code(404);
        $requestedPage = '404.php';
    }
?>
//HTML header info
<?php 
include("header.php");
include($requestedPage); 
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Far from secure, but it loads page's which is all I need right now. If we head over to my blog page, it has 3 files in total, `blog.php`, `blog_functions.php`, and `blog_template`.
`blog.php` is simply some HTML where I include the other two mentioned files, which is the bulk of the actual blog. I'm certain the issue isn't in `blog.php`, but here it is just to in case.

```
<?php include("includes/blog_functions.php");?>

//Some HTML
<section id="blog">
    <div class="blog-sidebar">
        <h3>Our recent posts</h3>
        <?php initPosts();?>
    </div>


<div class="blog-post">
<?php 
include("templates/blog_template.php");?>
</div>
</section>
```

This next file is `blog_functions.php`

```
<?php 
function sortRecentPosts($POST_DIR){
    $DIR = './blog_posts';
    $folders = array_slice(scandir($DIR), 2);
    usort($folders, function($a, $b) use ($POST_DIR) {
        //The array is just sending the file names, attach a path in this function 
        if(file_exists($POST_DIR.$a) && file_exists($POST_DIR.$b)){
            return filemtime($POST_DIR.$b) - filemtime($POST_DIR.$a);
        }
    });  
    return $folders;
}

function displayRecentPosts($folderArray, $POST_DIR){
    if(is_array($folderArray)){
        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
            echo "<h2><a href="."blog/".$folderArray[$i].">".$folderArray[$i]."</a></h2> \n";;
            echo date("d M, Y", filemtime($POST_DIR.$folderArray[$i]));
            echo "<img class=\"blog-post-header-img\"src=\"/".$POST_DIR.$folderArray[$i]."/header.jpg\" alt=\"Header image of blog post\">";
        }  
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('function did not recieve an array');
    }
}

function initPosts(){
    //POST_DIR controls the entire scripts working directory to find the blog posts.
    $POST_DIR = './blog_posts/';
    displayRecentPosts(sortRecentPosts($POST_DIR), $POST_DIR);
}
```

This is where I believe the problem to be. In `displayRecentPosts($a, $b)` there is a line where it echos out some HTML. One of the lines it echos is the  tag with a href to the actual blog post. As you can see, I start the string with with a hard coded `blog/`, followed up by the actual post, based on which post is clicked. While **not** having a blog post loaded, (for example just navigating to the blog page),
the url will look like this. `my-website.com/blog`. Now for example, let's now click on one of those links in the picture.

[image: Picture of what the blog sidebar looks like]

This will load a blog post, which will then change the URL to `my-website.com/blog/Test-Post2`. However, if I then try to navigate to another blog post in the same manner, it now will begin nesting the url, causing a 404.

[image: Picture of nested link structure]

For some reason, once a blog post is loaded, one scripts is grabbing and copying the link with the `blog/` prefix and applying again. However, if I inspect the  tag, it doesn't have the nested prefix. It looks like it should.

[image: The tag looks proper]

I have no idea what's causing this, or where it's coming from. I've ran through with a debugger on `index.php`, `blog_functions.php`, and `blog_template.php`. They all look fine and work as expected.

Here is `blog_template.php`. It only renders a post that it's given, nothing fancy.

```
<?php   
    $DIR = "./blog_posts";
    $folders = array_slice(scandir($DIR), 2);
    if(isset($_GET['blogPost'])){
        $blogPost = $_GET['blogPost'];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($folders as $arr){
            if($arr == $blogPost){
                chdir($DIR."/".$blogPost); 
                include(getcwd().'\\'.$blogPost.".html");
                chdir(__DIR__);
            }else{
                echo "NO MATCH ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }else{
        $blogPost = "";
        echo "FILE NAME IS NULL";
    }
?>
```

I don't suspect the issue to be here this file, as it only renders out the chosen page and stops afterwards.

Finally, I suppose the error could be in .htaccess, however I've never heard of or had an issue like this using `RewriteModule`, so if it is causing it, this is a first for me.

Actually, this is a first in general for me, I've never seen an  tag show something different than where the browser is actually going to send me, so I'm at a complete loss as to where this bug is coming from.

Here is `.htaccess` for clarity.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&blogPost=$2
```

Comment: Your URLs should start with a `/`. If it doesn't, it's going to assume that the URL is relative to the current directory, hence, `blog/blog`

Comment: @aynber Yep, that's what it was. What an oversight on my part. Thank you.